# How I can use transactions in TestNG @BeforeClass?

Tags: spring, hibernate, testng, spring-transactions

I use TestNG + Spring + hibernate.
When I use transaction in @BeforeClass, I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

Code example:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
@Rollback
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/WEB-INF/testing/applicationTestContext.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {
        ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class,
        WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
public abstract class ExampleOfTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpClass() {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction(); // get HibernateException
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    ....

}
```

How I can use transaction in @BeforeClass?
I want to use this for one-time data entry used in all class tests.

Answer (score 1):

Problem would be `@EnableTransactionManagement` should be in your spring context

or

Try something like

```
// BMT idiom with getCurrentSession()
try {
    UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext()
                            .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");

    tx.begin();

    // Do some work on Session bound to transaction
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(...);

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

getCurrentSession is like restricted, it should run in a active transaction.

I think this may help.